# Reason for a floating point exception?

Tags: c++, root-framework

This is part of a macro I am writing in the [ROOT](http://root.cern.ch) framework using C++ and some predefined classes. I get a floating point exception upon including the lines marked below (starting with `minv = ...`). What is the reason for this error?

```
Double_t ppx[3000],ppy[3000],ppz[3000],pE[3000];
Double_t m = 0.000511;
Double_t minv,epx,epy,epz,eE;
for(Int_t n = 0; n < nEvents; n++) {
  inTree->GetEntry(n);

  Int_t nTracks = trackArray->GetEntries();
  htrack->Fill(nTracks);
  for(Int_t i = 0; i < nTracks; i++) {
    Track* trackData = (Track*)trackArray->At(i);
    if(trackData->fCharge ==1)
    {
      ppx[i] = (trackData->fPt) * TMath::Cos(trackData->fPhi);
      ppy[i] = (trackData->fPt) * TMath::Sin(trackData->fPhi);
      ppz[i] = (trackData->fPt) * sinh(trackData->fEta);
      pE[i] = m * m  - ppx[i] * ppx[i] - ppy[i] * ppy[i] - ppz[i] * ppz[i];
    }
    hPt->Fill(trackData->fPt);
  }
  for(Int_t i = 0; i < nTracks; i++) {
    Track* trackData = (Track*)trackArray->At(i);
    if(trackData->fCharge == -1)

      for (Int_t k=0;k<nTracks;k++){
        epx = (trackData->fPt) * TMath::Cos(trackData->fPhi);
        epy = (trackData->fPt) * TMath::Sin(trackData->fPhi);
        epz = (trackData->fPt) * sinh(trackData->fEta);
        eE = m*m  - epx *epx - epy * epy - epz * epz;
        // the following two lines cause the exception:
        minv = ((eE +pE[k]) * (eE + pE[k])) - ((epx + ppx[k]) * (epx + ppx[k])) - ((epy + ppy[k]) * (epy + ppy[k])) - ((epz + ppz[k]) * (epz + ppz[k])    );
        invm->Fill(minv);
      }
  }
}

nEventsProcessed++;
}
```

PS: I know this is not very efficient coding, I am a beginner.

I printed out the values of minv. Here is a small sample indicative of the output

```
-0.225634
-0.657662
-0.225634
1.53201
-0.225634
nan
-0.630927
-0.225634
-0.225634
-0.225634
-0.225634
-0.228794
-0.225634
-0.7196
-0.225634
-0.225634
-0.520265
-0.228796
0.608326
-0.225634
-0.225634
-0.225634
-0.733564
2.74301
-0.763932
-0.225634
-0.225634
nan
-0.228643
-0.225634
-0.225634
-0.225634
-0.584549
```

Addition: The nan's are very strange. The numbers in their vicinity look normal and this is not a function that blows up, so am I using into junk values of the array?

Comment: What is the value of `minv` you're passing to `invm->Fill(minv)`? ... You should be capable of seeing that value in a debugger ... when you say removing those two lines removes the exception, then you are either getting it on the calculation of `minv`, or something happening in your `invm` object.

Comment: Besides that we have no idea what Fill() in line 119 does, you should maybe print out the values at the point of exception to see what it is trying to calculate.

Comment: @PlasmaHH Fill() is a routine to populate entries in a histogram.

Comment: If it is related with matrix inversion, it could be a division by zero.

Comment: @Andreas http://root.cern.ch/root/html/TTree.html#TTree:Fill

Comment: Do you still get the exception if you include line 118 but exclude line 119?

Comment: @Steve, if I set the value of minv to some dummy value (otbherwise there is no value to Fill) then there is no error. The error is surely in line 118

Comment: Do you still get the exception if you replace `Int_t nTracks = trackArray->GetEntries();` with `const int nTracks = (int)trackArray->GetEntries();`

Comment: @Jason I have edited some representative values of minv from the output before the program crashes

Comment: @wok I made the replacement and the floating point exception is still there

Comment: @yayu Don't you have a debugger?

Comment: You have `nan` a few times. That's quite likely the cause of the error. It seems to me that you need to debug the expression that gives you `minv`.

Comment: @Andreas no, I use vim editor, and the ROOT platform. I dont know how to use a debugger (not sure it is available for ROOT)

Comment: BTW are you running this as a compiled C++ program? If so I suggest debugging it with `gdb`.

Comment: @juanchopanza The `nan` 's are very strange. The numbers in their viscinity look normal and this is not a function that blows up.. am I using into junk values of the array?

Comment: If you don't have a debugger you'll have to resort to good old printf debugging. Before you calculate `minv` print all the variables that are used to calculate it and see which one is faulty (make sure you flush the output).

Comment: There are **NaN** values in the set of your samples. These are your exceptions. You need to figure out how these values were generated. Run your program in the debugger an stop at line 119 when `isnan(minv)`, then examine the variables that make up the value of minv, etc.

Comment: I think you'll need to check the value of every element in the `minv` expression. As for debugging, assuming you're on linux or mac osx, try `which gdb`. For using `gdb` see, for example, http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~gilpin/tutorial/

Comment: @juan and everyone thank you very much. I will now try to find the error, but thanks to you all I know understand the cause of the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first loop over all tracks, you only fill the arrays if the track charge is positive. In the second loop, you access the arrays no matter whether the charge of the k-th track is positive.

If you want to fill `minv` (I guess the invariant mass) only for opposite-charged tracks, remove the first `if` that checks for a positive charge and change the last loop to:

```
for (Int_t i=0; i<nTracks; i++) {
    Track* trackData = (Track*)trackArray->At(i);
    for (Int_t k=0; k<nTracks; k++){
        Track* trackData2 = (Track*)trackArray->At(k);
        if (trackData->fCharge == trackData2->fCharge)
            continue;

        // calculate minv here
        invm->Fill(minv);
    }
}
```

Comment: Btw, this algorithm is different from mine. In my case, I am assured that all charges have the same magnitude, and I am to find the invariant mass of positive negative pairs, which is why I had two if statements.

Comment: Ah OK, I thought that was accidental. Well, it should be easy to change.